# Table Column Freeze Not Working in Google Chrome and Mircrosoft Edge

Tags: css, vb.net

Column freeze is working in Internet Explorer but upon checking in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge it didn't work. Is there any possible solution to make this work to Chrome and Microsoft Edge (see codes below) or can you recommend any best solution to freeze the table column that can work to different browser? Thanks in advance.

IE: 
[image]

Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge:
[image]

Invalid property value
[image]

Here's the code:

```
   <style type="text/css">
        td.locked {
            border-top: 0px;
            border-right: 0px;
            position: relative;
            left: expression(document.getElementById("<%= pnlItemDetails.ClientID %>").scrollLeft-2410);
        }

        th.locked {
            border-right: 0px;
            position: relative;
            left: expression(document.getElementById("<%= pnlItemDetails.ClientID %>").scrollLeft-2410);
        }
   </style>

 Protected Sub gvwItemDetails_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvwItemDetails.RowDataBound

            Select Case e.Row.RowType
                Case DataControlRowType.DataRow

                    If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Alternate Then
                        ' Highlights the alternate row when hover
                        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className='onmouseover_alternate'")
                        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className='onmouseout_alternate'")
                        e.Row.Attributes.Add("class", "gridviewclass_alternate")
                    Else
                        ' Highlights the row when hover
                        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className='onmouseover'")
                        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className='onmouseout'")
                        e.Row.Attributes.Add("class", "gridviewclass")
                    End If

                    ' Lock last columns
                    e.Row.Cells(25).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                    e.Row.Cells(26).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                    e.Row.Cells(27).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                    e.Row.Cells(28).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                    e.Row.Cells(29).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                Case DataControlRowType.Header
                    ' Lock last columns
                    e.Row.Cells(25).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                    e.Row.Cells(26).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                    e.Row.Cells(27).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                    e.Row.Cells(28).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                    e.Row.Cells(29).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                Case DataControlRowType.Footer

                        e.Row.Cells(24).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                        e.Row.Cells(25).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                        e.Row.Cells(26).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                        e.Row.Cells(27).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                        e.Row.Cells(28).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                        e.Row.Cells(29).Attributes.Add("class", "locked")
                    End If
            End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Mark `position:fixed`?

Comment: @Manjuboyz, I tried but the freeze columns are now missing / not showing anymore

Comment: is it a `<table>` or `div`??

Comment: @sumeshsn1, columns from GridView